# Edit only one line in a file containing identical paths (shell using sed)

Tags: linux, shell, sed, path, sh

I have a file like this

```
/path/to/first/file.sh
/path/to/first/file.sh
/path/to/first/file2.sh
```

and at the end of each line I want to add a comment depending on the file's execution. The result may change for the same path.

For now I was doing a loop with `while read path` and for each `path` :

```
sed s~path~path+comment~g
```

But when I have the same path multiple times, the comment is added multiple times. For example I get `/path/to/first/file.sh+comment+comment` because `file.sh` appears twice in this file.

What do you suggest to do ?

**EDIT:**

I want something like this :

```
/path/to/first/file.sh+comment1
/path/to/first/file.sh+comment2
/path/to/first/file2.sh+comment3
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to edit the file in place as you go along. I would read a line (inside a `while read line` loop) and write either the unchanged `"$line"` or a commented line`"$line+comment"` to a growing tmp file. Once you have finished processing your list, you can rename the temp file back to the original. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shellter. The real situation is a bit more complex : I have the value of a path and I have to add a comment only once on the corresponding line. Something like if I was executing all files separately and each file knowing its path and its return value edits the initial list.

Comment: Again, my point is, rather than complicate the logic by managing "edits(ing) the initial list", just make a new result file using your list file to drive the process. This has the added benefit, that you could name it like `myProcess_Results_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H:%M).txt` to make a self-documenting trace of when `myProcess` has been run. Good luck.

Comment: Ah yes, ad re-reading your Q, you are already doing `while read path (or line)`. So just echo what you need into a result/log file. If you dont want/can't have 2 files, then when `myProcess` is done, overwrite the list file with the log file. Good luck;-)!